# Iterate member variables

Tags: delphi, variables, delphi-2010, member, loops

Is there a way to iterate the member variables of an object in D2010 without knowing what they are beforehand?

Comment: which version of delphi are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're using Delphi 2010 or later.  You can use extended RTTI to get information about an object's fields, methods and properties.  Simple version:

```
procedure GetInfo(obj: TObject);
var
  context: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  field: TRttiField;
  method: TRttiMethod;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  context := TRttiContext.Create;
  rType := context.GetType(obj.ClassType);
  for field in rType.GetFields do
    ;//do something here
  for method in rType.GetMethods do
    ;//do something here
  for prop in rType.GetProperties do
    ;//do something here
end;
```

The necessary objects can be found in the `RTTI` unit.

In earlier versions of Delphi, there's some more limited RTTI that can get you some information about some properties and methods, but it can't do all that much.

Comment: Do the methods/fields/properties have to be `published` or can they be normal?

Comment: @John: By default, extended RTTI is generated for all fields, and `public` or `published` properties and methods.  This can be changed in code you write by using the `{$RTTI}` compiler directive, but it's pretty much baked in for the standard libraries, unless you use modified versions of them.  (Which is possible, but officially discouraged by Embarcadero.)

Comment: Hmm, Borland was pretty friendy toward RTL rebuilding, did they change policy recently?